# Tailwindcss - align two texts with different sizes to bottom line

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

[image]

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-1 text-sm bg-red-300">
       <span class="align-bottom">I want this to be on the same bottom level as Right content</span>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-1 text-right  text-5xl bg-blue-400">
    Right content
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried `align-bottom`,`align-text-bottom` or something with `float-right` and `float-left` (without using flex), but nothing worked so far..

Tailwind [Playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/XJtr3UgFrb?layout=horizontal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [`items-end`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/align-items) on the parent along with `flex` class to solve the problem.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-1 text-sm bg-red-300 flex items-end">
    <span>I want this to be on the same bottom level as Right content</span>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-1 text-right  text-5xl bg-blue-400">
    Right content
  </div>
</div>
```

[Tailwind Playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/4PHAjjxs6s?layout=horizontal)